# Renew a Existing Memberships With Drupal Webform

Tags: civimember, webform-civicrm

I have a Webform that collects lots of information and allows for a user to purchase several different types of memberships. What it does not let the user do is renew an existing membership.

I am trying to come up with a good way where a user who does not have a Drupal user account can go to a Webform and renew their membership rather than create anew one.

In theory this works by just using the matching email address.  However, when we have a matching email address transaction we get this error, "It appears that this transaction is a duplicate. Have you already submitted the form once? If so there may have been a connection problem. Check your email for a receipt from Authorize.net. If you do not receive a receipt within 2 hours you can try your transaction again. If you continue to have problems please contact the site administrator."

It is possible that some of the custom JS in my form is breaking the renewal process but I do not see why that would cause a problem.  The correct value is being given to Civi Contribute for the financial transaction.

For the time being we are okay with just having renewals based on matching email addresses in the form.

Thanks,
Steve

Comment: You don't specifically mention sending the contact a link to the form with a checksum. Have you considered this? Are you aware of this option? Is this not an option because people need to do this independent of your system sending them Scheduled Reminders with a checksum link? If so, another option we have made use of is to get anonymous users to fill in a first form, which then sends them an email with the checksum link